# How could this kind of rewrite be laid in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

In a htaccess already containing this lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

That rewrite urls from their original:

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?page=this-is-the-title
```

to

```
http://www.domain.com/this-is-the-tile
```

My question is, that the original url with the string index.php?page= is still accessible, and if there could be some line i could add before or after those, or some modification of the lines already there, to redirect 301 it to the second kind one url, so whenever someone try to access it, browser automatically load the one without the index and query string.

I tried simply, adding a r=301 flag on the qsa line, but that broke everything with a 500 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need this additional rule:

```
# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
```